# Getting "WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI ..." when trying to setup spring servlet

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to setup a Spring MVC project. I have added a dispatcher servlet, a jsp and setup the web.xml file. But I keep getting

> WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/safesite/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Here's my web.xml

```
...
<context-param>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- To load the Spring context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.activiti.explorer.servlet.WebConfigurer</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- To allow session-scoped beans in Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>UIFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.activiti.explorer.filter.ExplorerFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>JSONPFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.activiti.explorer.servlet.JsonpCallbackFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UIFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/o/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JSONPFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.activiti.explorer.servlet.ExplorerApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>org.activiti.explorer.CustomWidgetset</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Session timeout on one day -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>480</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

And here is my HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.activiti.explorer.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

My HelloController

```
 package org.activiti.explorer.controller;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

 /**
  *
  * @author Fionn
  */
 @Controller
 public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

         String message = "<br><div align='center'>"
                 + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is comming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********<br><br>";
         return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
     }
}
```

And my hello.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"     %>
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
```

I can't figure this one out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And which you url you are trying to access  ?

Comment: You can simply access `/hello.jsp`

Comment: No that's what I'm trying to do. safesite is the webapp name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.activiti.explorer.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

note that I've removed the version from the xsd files, this means that it will use the schema from your jar files (and there will be a validation error in case of incompatibilty)

after @Nikolay's comment, I've also noticed an error in your mapping (note that you still need the annotation-driven element), you should either change the mapping in your controller to

```
@RequestMapping("/hello.jsp")
```

and access it via

```
/safesite/hello.jsp
```

**OR**, more common, change the servlet mapping to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and access as Nikolay said so `/safesite/hello`

Comment: replace my HelloWeb-servlet with this?

Comment: not replace, merge, you need to add the annotation element, and the you  need to include the mvc namespace, but you also need your two existing elements (component-scan and view resolver) I've just copy pasted an excerpt, that has everything you need, you should be able to find your way in merging easialy

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still get the same warning.

Comment: no problem, noticed another thing and editied in the response, hope it'll help

Comment: Could you explain why this fixed it? Should my url not have .jsp at the end of it?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue before which was very confusing, after a series of tests, I found it's the url-pattern for the DispatcherServlet. 
Be cautious when you use the asterisk for wildcard match which might lead to unexpected behavior, and it's just safe to start from root "/" or your custom servlet context path "/foo/"

Try the following.

```html
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got that error when i migrated/updated from Spring framework 3.X to 4.X and using json (through Jackson2) as returned object and got the error above.

To solve that you should add

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean  class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
           <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
       </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

To XXX-servlet.xml file

And on the code you should use MappingJackson2JsonView as return value 
for example :

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
MappingJackson2JsonView user() {
MappingJackson2JsonView view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
view.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);
view.addStaticAttribute("user", new User("Sébastien", "Deleuze"));
view.setPrefixJson(true);
return view;
}
```

for more examples look here:
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView