# Route mapping won't work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new in the Java web applications. Have created simple HelloWorld program, following tutorials on the internet with Spring MVC framework. But, I can't find the reason why the path `TestWebApp/helloWorld.htm` won't work (**404 error** all the time).

If I look in the **GlassFish 4.1** server log, it shows this:

```
Info:   Mapped URL path [/helloworld] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Info:   Mapped URL path [/helloworld/*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
        String message = "Hello Spring MVC!";
        return new ModelAndView("helloWorld", "message", message);
    }
}
```

**helloWorld.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="testapp"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->   
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>       
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

**Project structure:**
[image]

I have found a lot of similar questions to this, but it appears that no answer from there solves the issue here.

Comment: you seem to be missing the annotation-driven element that e.g. check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364163/getting-warn-org-springframework-web-servlet-pagenotfound-no-mapping-found-fo/28364345#28364345, only the part about the missing element applies to your case

Comment: @MasterSlave Can you please make it as full post, so I can accept it as answer?

Comment: did it, marking as a duplicate is also an option, but the other question had an additional issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

element inside your servlet configuration. The element will generate the handlers for all the *@RequestMapping* annotated methods defined in the  controller classes.

The proper namespace must be included as well, a relevent excerpt

```
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
```

Comment: Also, this lines need to be added.  `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`  And in `xsi:schemaLocation` needs to be added: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd`

Comment: yeps, added in the answer and expained briefly

Answer (score 0):

Your controller definition has the request mapping as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

But the way you are accessing your web app it should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloWorld.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: That is definitely required as that is the url you are accessing. What is the context path of your webapp and what is the precise url you are using to access the page.