# 404 error for Spring MVC Rest URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am making a dummy hello world applicatiion for Spring MVC, i have done exactly same as was mentioned in example, but when i run the URL, its giving me the 404 error. Please help me if you can, following are my files:-

```
web.xml

    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="moqahServices"/>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>moqahServices</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>moqahServices</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>


    moqahServices.xml

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.moqah" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>

 HelloController.jsp

    package com.moqah;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }
}



Please let me know if you have any suggestions
```

Comment: Have tried to open the page in a browser? What happens?

Comment: did you try with `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`?

Comment: you seem to be missing the mvc:annotation-driven element, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364163/getting-warn-org-springframework-web-servlet-pagenotfound-no-mapping-found-fo/28364345#28364345

Answer (score 0):

i guess the mvc:annotation-driven element should be used in your moqahServices, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code it seems,

1) you configured `mvc:default-servlet-handler` in the wrong place. It should be the part of your spring configurations.

2) In `web.xml` considering the `servlet-name` as `moqahServices`, spring configuration name should be suffixed with `-servlet.xml`  followed by `servlet-name` ie. your spring configuration name is expected as `moqahServices-servlet.xml`

Please Try doing above changes.